# CakePHP: Best practice for app-wide media-uploads

Tags: cakephp, upload

I'm trying to make an App-wide media-upload which should have the possibility of being accessible from every controller/model.
I thought of on table `media` which holds record of all uploaded files, my schema looks like this:

```
id
controller      //to keep the reference from which controller the file was uploaded
foreign_key     //since files should be uploaded to specific records, I need this id
filename
extension
fullname
size
created
modified
```

I'm not sure what would be the best approach in doing this. I've thought of components, plugins and a behavior but still am unsure.

My App has many different controllers with different records.
For example it manages projects and should now be able to attach PDFs to specific projects from within the project-edit mask.
Since this is a feature needed by other controllers, too I want to write it application wide.

I'm pretty sure I need a helper to call the upload-function from within the masks.
May something like: `echo $this->Media->uploadMask();` which provides me with an ready uploading-mask for the controller and id I'm editing at the moment.

But I don't know which route I should call for the upload. Something like `/media/upload` would be very good, but I'm not sure if this fits correctly into the MVC-approach.
Would it be better to call it from my specific controllers? Or is an AJAX-upload to just a normal controller/model like better?

Comment: The Media plugin - mentioned below - does exactly this, using a single `attachments` table with the following schema: id, model, foreign_key, dirname, basename, checksum, group, alternative, created, modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is a [Behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1071/Behaviors), which is basically an object of methods that can apply to any model. For controllers there are also [Components](http://book.cakephp.org/view/994/Introduction).

There are already a couple of established upload behaviours for CakePHP you should check out: [Meio Upload](https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload) which is good for basic image manipulation and also the [CakePHP Media Plugin](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/tree) which is more advanced and more recently updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to the Media Plugin. Exactly what I was searching for (but unfortunately couldn't find ;))